# AJAX failed to callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I'm using ajax to `update` form data to database, if success, it'll return some text back, however it's not working

**html**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value=""  placeholder="name..." >
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="email"  value="" placeholder="email..." >
                    <br>
                    <button id="form-btn" class="btn btn-default" onclick="update()">click me</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><span id="result">here</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**js**

```
function update() {

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState = 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      // document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_form.php",true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  var str = $("form").serialize();
  xmlhttp.send(str);
}
```

**php**

```
  $name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

if ($sql_insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $tablename (name, email) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
    # Bind the variables to the parameter as strings
    if (!$sql_insert->bind_param("ss", $name, $email)) {
        echo "binding parameter fail";
    }

# Execute the statement
if (!$sql_insert->execute()) {
    echo "insert fail: " . $sql_insert->error .  "<br>";

} else {
    echo "success";
}

# Close the prepared statement
$sql_insert->close();               
}
```

The result what I'm expecting is: When user submit the form, it'll inform user that it update successfully in `<span id='result'></span>`, but it just update the data without inform.

Comment: So why is jQuery tagged though the code has zero jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't comment on your post because of the reputation. But there is error on your code. You missed one equalto sign

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState = 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
```

should be

if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)

Comment: thanks! bro, i couldn't believe that i lost that "=" in my code, however when i correct this error, it's still not working :(

Comment: @HuangLiang-Syun  Is the database being updated? If database is updated i don't see anything wrong in your code .Have you tried clearing browser cache? sometimes it also causes that problem

Answer (score 0):

This is what works using jQuery ajax.
the similar should work using your code.
Try putting alerts in the callback functions.

```
$.ajax({
        url: ...,
        type: ...,
        data: ...,
        async:false,
        error: function(data){ // callback triggers almost directly after returning

            $("#result").html("Error occurred");
        }, 
        success: function(data){
            $("#result").html("update successful");
        }
    });
```

Comment: hi Waqar, i have a question in your code: why don't let async be true?

Comment: I have delibrately kept async false, cause sometimes response from the server comes a little late and if you javascript is dependent on the response and you are writing code that is not in the success callback your response will not be available. Async false makes sure your page to wait and not render any javascript.